# How not to grab default value of inputbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, inputbox

I am grabbing the value of input box and passing to the URL as querystring. I dont want to grab the default value "Enter Keywords(address....) which is controlled to show or hide by the following:

```
    //**onClick and OnLostFocus (focus and blur) events on textareas and input textboxes**
   $('input[type="text"], textarea').focus(function () {
        defaultText = $(this).val();
        $(this).val('');
    });
    $('input[type="text"], textarea').blur(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == "") {
            $(this).val(defaultText);
        }
    }); 


<input name="KeywordBox" class="BasicSearchInputBox" type="text" size="300" value="Enter Keywords (address,city and state OR zipcode)"/>
```

How not to grab the default text but just user input?? in jquery?

Comment: Use the onchange event instead and check that the text entered isn't the default text.

Answer (score 1):

I usually add some default class name to the input field, then clear it when the user types. That way I can tell if the default "watermark" text is there, or user data.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to do this would be to use `placeholder` and fallback for older browsers.
For your current problem you can just check for that default text when you grab the value. Something like:

```
$('form').submit(function(){
    if (~$('input').val().indexOf(defaultText)) {
        // Not found, do your ajax stuff
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you have above doesn't really do default values (placeholder). If someone first types 'anything' into the field, then clears the value from the field, your code will reset it to 'anything' instead of 'Enter Keywords...'

You need a plugin like http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/defaultvalue

```
<input placeholder="Enter a username…" type="text">
<input placeholder="…and a password" type="password">
<script>
$(' [placeholder] ').defaultValue();
</script>
```

If you really want to write it on your own, the simplest steps are

- Add a placeholder property in the input field
- onfocus: clear input.value if input.value equals input.placeholder
- onblur: set input.value to input.placeholder if input.value is empty

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with something like:

```
function togglePrompt() {
  if (this.value == this.defaultValue) {
    this.value = '';
  } else if (this.value == '') {
    this.value = this.defaultValue;
  }
}

window.onload = function() {
  var el = document.getElementById('inp0');
  el.onfocus = togglePrompt;
  el.onblur = togglePrompt;
}


<input value="Enter text..." id="inp0">
```